# Use DateTimeOffset in NEST DateRange predicate

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a simple NEST query with DateRanges predicate:

```
DateTimeOffset dt;
...
.DateRange(r => r
    .Field("Time")
    .LessThanOrEquals(dt)
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906142/datetimeoffset-to-datetime-conversion-data-loss), simply converting `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime` **might cause data loss**. `LessThanOrEquals` and other predicate methods accept object of the `Nest.DateMath` type, which has the following operators:

```
public static implicit operator DateMath(DateTime dateTime);
public static implicit operator DateMath(string dateMath);
```

In addition `DateRangeQueryDescriptor` has an additional method:

```
public DateRangeQueryDescriptor<T> TimeZone(string timeZone);
```

but I'm not sure how to use it.

**QUESTION**:

How can I use a `DateTimeOffset` object as a value for `DateRange` predicate in `NEST` and be sure that the dates sent to Elastic are the correct ones?

Comment: According to the referenced post you mentioned, you could use the converted `DateTime` together with `Offset` (converted to `TimeZone`) to be used? I would ask additional challenge that why you have `DateTimeOffset` at the first place.

Comment: Could be. I want to make sure I'm not making a stupid mistake here.

In the mentioned question, you can find a reason why to prefer `DateTimeOffset` over `DateTime` - in our case it's necessary. 

Here's the way to convert `TimeSpan` to `TimeZone` string.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420648/1151392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I was wrong.

According to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), all dates are stored or must be stored as UTC, thus the range parameters should be passed as UTC as well.

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.